# wavelet transform opencl for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, opencl, wavelet

I want to code a wavelet transform in an OpenCL 1.0 kernel. I know how to do this in C language but I don't in OpenCL. What i want to know is how to browse the image with for loops. In C language i do :

```
for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
  {
    for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
      v[i+j*m] = u[i+j*m];
    }
  }
```

With m and n the size of the image. In OpenCL i can't do this. I have just the beginning of my kernel :

```
__kernel void wavelet(__global float* output, __global float* input1,)
{
    int WIDTH = 320; 
    int HEIGHT = 200;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    const int column = get_global_id(0);
    const int row = get_global_id(1);   
}
```

How am I suppose to code the two for loops in OpenCL ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Each dimension of your kernel "unwraps" one for-loop into a parallel process. You have a 2D kernel, **so you should need no loops at all in your kernel.** Think of the `row` and `column` variables in your kernel as `i` and `j` (or `j` and `i`, depending on how you have things set up) in your C code.

Its somewhat more difficult when trying to accumulate values between different locations in the image. Each work-item runs in parallel, introducing potential race conditions. You may need one or more for-loops in your kernel to accumulate values sequentially.

In OpenCL 2.2 and greater, variable-duration loops are possible, and their syntax is identical to C. You can extract the image dimensions in your kernel using `get_global_size(uint dimindx)`.

Make sure to call `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` with the right number of dimensions. You also need `global_size` in this call to match your image dimensions. For instance, `int global_size[2] = {w,h}`. Your `local_size` can be any value smaller than your global size, but I like to work with `int local_size[2]={16,16};`. I've found that OpenCL kernels may sometimes fail completely if the `local_size` to `global_size` ratio is sub-optimal. For guaranteed results, you can set `local_size` to `{1,1}`.